# Why is the length of nested array returning as undefined even after I've just pushed a new array?

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays, slack, slack-api

I've been working on a Slack app for some time now. I have a button which creates a submission ID based on the persons user ID and name which will be pushed into an array along with some other information collected from future modal inputs. That array is then pushed into another database array to track all the submission arrays.

I am trying to build a function to iterate through the nested array and check if the param (submissionId) is already in the nested array.

When I run my code it returns "TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined."

In my code you will see I push a new subarray to my parent array before I check with my if-statement. Why would it be returning undefined? There is indeed a sub array to check the length of.

```
  // Function to check if submission ID already exists in DB
  function checkDupe(submissionId) {
  
  // Result to track if ID is found or not, view to return the correct view based on result
  let result;
  let view;

  // Push new array for the sake of testing; should always return true in this case
  payrollDb.push(new Array(submissionId));

  // This logs correctly with the submissionId param
  console.log(payrollDb[0][0]);

  // Nested for-loop to iterate through subarray values and check for submissionId
  for(let i=0; i<payrollDb.length; i++) {
    for(let j=0; j<payrollDb[i].length; j++) {
       console.log(submissionId,"\n", payrollDb[i][j]);
      payrollDb[i][j] === submissionId ? result = true : result = false;
    }
    
  };

  // If found, return the error modal, if not continue with the next modal.
  result ? view = views_payroll_duplicate : view = views_payroll_period;

  return view;
  
}
```

I am at a loss here. I just want it to check if the submissionId already exists in my "database" and if so, return one JSON body and if it does not find a duplicate then return the other JSON body.

Any suggestions on how to fix OR even to improve what I have would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Haven't gone through the whole code, but I do notice that you do not break out of the loop in case submissionId is found, meaning that the next iteration result can be set to false again.
Also `result ? view = views_payroll_duplicate : view = views_payroll_period;` Do you perhaps meant to do `view = result ? views_payroll_duplicate  : views_payroll_period` to do the actual assigning?

Comment: payrollDb could have a value that isn't an array, can't see where it comes from there, provide enough reproducible code

Comment: It looks like you're expecting `new Array(n)` to return `[n]`, when it actually returns _`[empty x n]`_.

Comment: Since `payrollDb` seems to be instanciated (and maybe modified) outside your function, we cannot know what it contains. Either, you first check a length property can be read, either you make sure `payrollDb` only contains expected values.

Answer (score 1):

I would wager that one of the payrollDb[i] is undefined. After this line:

`for(let i=0; i<payrollDb.length; i++) {`

Add a check to log the [i] before your next loop. Then when it errors the location that is causing an issue should show up, and you should be able to code around it. You could also wrap the second for in a conditional to skip it if it's undefined.

```
  for(let i=0; i<payrollDb.length; i++) {
      if ([i] === undefined) { // check the type equals undefined
          for(let j=0; j<payrollDb[i].length; j++) {
```

Comment: I added the check right after the first for loop and it correctly logs out the data I pushed prior. I also added an if to stop if it's undefined but it goes ahead and then STILL says undefined. It's as if it's all fine right up to when I check the length and then it's like ??? DNE, bro.

Comment: Quantum arrays, wherein the result changes when it's measured. hahaha.

Answer (score 0):

Well it seems I've found the issue. To be honest I am not sure why this worked but it did.

I added a variable prior to the loops equal to the length of the array I was about to loop through and then used that in my for loop instead of directly calling payrollDb.length or payrollDb[i].length.

The updated code is as follows.

```
function checkDupe(submissionId) {

  let result;
  let view;

  // Set variable for outer array length
  let n = payrollDb.length;
  for(let i=0; i<n; i++) {

    // Set variable for inner array length
    let m = payrollDb[i].length;
    for(let j=0; j<m; j++) {
      payrollDb[i][j] === submissionId ? result = true : result = false;
    }
  };

  result ? view = views_payroll_duplicate : view = views_payroll_period;

  return view;
  
}
```

If somebody could explain further that would be great!!!